# Make a input only allow names and not numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have this:

```
personname: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.test(value);
}
```

But when the name is Pëter Müller or something like that it is invalid, how can I add all those possible characters within my code and what are those character codes?

Comment: Off-topic but still relevant: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: You shouldn't validate names, as you'll never get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `/^\D+$/`? It matches when all are not digits.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark it as an answer in 12 minutes (than I can mark it)

Comment: Then 50 Cent decides to join your site, and get's "name invalid", and writes a tweet about your stupid website, and you're screwed.

Comment: @adeneo I don't think that a name like that does exist, but you are having a point

Comment: @Henk - It's a [stage name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50_Cent), but the point still stands, you shouldn't validate names other than make sure the name doesn't contain code etc.

Comment: @adeneo +1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_(musician) "_After changing his stage name to an unpronounceable symbol (Prince logo.svg), also known as the "Love Symbol", in 1993, he began releasing new albums at a faster pace to remove himself from contractual obligations to_" http://upload.wikimedia.org